Chromedriver 124 is only available for Beta and that is giving error: "Unable to Kill Process"
My Chrome browser is updated to version 124.
But chrome driver for this version (stable version) is not yet available.
I downloaded the beta version.
The test seems to be working, but at the end of the test, I see errors:
Unable to drain process streams and
Unable to kill process.
My CPU usage goes to 100% and the server is not usable unless I manually kill the process.
Is there a link to check when newer version of Chrome driver will be available?
Enter image description here
Enter image description here

Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code, HTML, or errors are not. Please read why a screenshot of code/HTML/errors is a bad idea. Edit your question and add the code/HTML/errors as text, properly formatted.

Revert to chrome v123 from here until there is a stable v124 chromedriver available.

alternatively you can revert to 123 chromedriver and use environment variable:  In Java that would be: System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.disableBuildCheck", "true");  (hopefully this is a bug in the beta driver and not in Chrome itself)

@Kdave did you report it to the chrome team?

Please review Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? (e.g., "Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface.") and do the right thing. Thanks in advance.

As of Selenium 4.6, you no longer need to manage your browser drivers. Selenium Manager was added and will automatically download, configure, and use the appropriate browser driver. Your code would look like
from selenium import webdriver

url = "about:blank"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

