Chromedriver 124 is only available for Beta and that is giving error: "Unable to Kill Process" how?
0
My Chromebrowser is updated to version 124. But chrome driver for this version (stable version) is not yet available. I downloaded Beta version. Test seems to be working but at the end of the test, I see errors: Unable to drain process streams and Unable to kill process. My CPU usage goes to 100% and server is not usable unless I manually kill the process. Is there a link to check when newer version of Chrome driver will be available ? Any one experiencing similar issue in last couple of days
solve this issue or oldest driver

Did you copy paste the same question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78349830/chromedriver-124-is-only-available-for-beta-and-that-is-giving-error-unable-to

This may actually be a bug in Chrome.  There's a recursive check in the DOM that was recently optimized... however they introduced a bug that would crash the browser in certain circumstances.  This may have also affected the driver's quit method.  https://issues.chromium.org/issues/335553723
